# Transitions not working inside NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-animation

I am trying to navigate between two views without a `NavigationLink`.

Here is the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct NextView: View {
    
    @State var text = ""
    @Binding var displayView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        // 3
        //NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                TextField("Type something!", text: $text)
                Button("Remove View") {
                    withAnimation {
                        displayView = false
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }.background(Color.cyan)
        //}
    }
}

struct InitialView: View {
    
    @State var displayView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        // 1
        //NavigationView {
            if displayView {
                //2
                //NavigationView {
                    NextView(displayView: $displayView)
                        .transition(.slide)
                
                //}
            } else {
                Button("Tap to continue") {
                    withAnimation {
                        displayView = true
                    }
                }
            }
        //}
    }
}
```

I tried to place the `NavigationView` in 3 different places, one at a time. I managed to get the animation I wanted only by placing the structure in position **3** or not using it. Could anyone tell me why this happens and other possible solutions to use the `NavigationView` in position 1?

I tested only in the iPhone 12 simulator and am using XCode Version 13.4.1.

Comment: If you want to navigate (ie. transition) w/o NavigationLink why do you need NavigationView then? NavigationView is not needed for transition.

Comment: I wanted to have a ToolBar in some Views. Of course one option is to make my own with an HStack but I wanted my `InitialView` to make transitions between different Views, including those who have a ToolBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just wanted this - animatable transition

```
struct InitialView: View {

    @State var displayView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {   // << just root view, not important
            ZStack {                  // << owner container !!
                if displayView {
                    NextView(displayView: $displayView)
                        .transition(.slide)
                } else {
                    Button("Tap to continue") {
                        displayView = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .animation(.default, value: displayView)   // << animation !!
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Thank you! Could you maybe provide a bit more of information about the need for an owner container, which in your solution is a ZStack?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question. If you look closely at your code, you see that in postion 3 `.transition` is applied to the `NavigationView`. However, in positions 1 & 2 it’s not.

Transitions must be applied to the `View` that is transitioning, in your case, it’s the `NavigationView` that is wrapping the content. Implying that the `NavigationView` needs the `modifier`.

Add the transition to the `NavigationView` in any position & it should work as expected.